# Simple SQL Query Statement syntax error

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007

Im new to databases and never used Access 2007 before, Im having trouble syntax wise. This is the info

```
Teacher = [CourseN, Quarter,TeacherName]
Course = [CourseN,CourseName, Nunit)
Section = [CourseN, Quarter , DayTime,  RoomN]/ Examples of DayTime: M2:00AM, 
W4:50PM, and T8:00PM. Note that DayTime is represented as a string.
Student = [studentName, CourseN, Quarter]
```

The question

12.Use ‘*’ to list the CourseN, CourseName, Nunit, Quarter, TeacherName of every course sorted by CourseN ascending, CourseName descending.

My answer

```
 SELECT CourseN, CourseName, Nunit, Quarter, TeacherName 
 FROM *
 ORDER BY CourseN ASC, CourseName DESC;
```

but this is giving me a error for the FROM clause, how can i fix this syntax error? or is it that i cant do this? any info would be great, thanks

Edit: I know i can do it like this right?

```
SELECT C.CourseN, C.CourseName, C.Nunit, T.Quarter, T.TeacherName
FROM Course C, Teacher T
WHERE T.CourseN = C.CourseN
ORDER BY C.CourseN ASC, C.CourseName DESC;
```

Comment: The question you were set is stupid. Firstly, you can't "use *" to do it, and secondly the second order by criteria (name) is nonsensical, since CourseN is the primary key and therefore unique - ordering by that renders all subsequent criteria irrelevant

Comment: yea i figured this teacher is a 70 year old tenured teacher that just doesnt care anymore sadly it gets confusing really quick @Bohemian, but the second why i did it, its okay right?

Comment: Yes it would work, but you should use proper join syntax - the syntax you used was deprecated 25 years ago (no exaggeration)

Comment: @Bohemian of course it is, thats what i get for taking this teacher, hes way to old school and doesnt care anymore, but man i really need the classes :(  Thanks for the heads up tho ill try to learn the new stuff on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put `*` in a `FROM` clause! You must explicitly define which tables you want to use.

A second thought: Although you can define relations between tables in the `WHERE` clause, it's better (or at least clearer) if you define the relation in the `FROM` clause, using `INNER JOIN`:

```
select c.courseN, c. courseName, c.Nunit, t.quarter, t.teacherName
from course as c
     inner join teacher as t on c.counrseN = t.courseN
```

Comment: ive heard of the join clause but we havent covered it in class yet idk if we can use it, @Barranka the second way is okay tho right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. As far as i remember it's called "implicit join". The `inner join ` defines an explicit join. Also, consider Bohemian's comment regarding the `order by`

Comment: Okay Thanks @Barranka, ill just leave as it is i dont feel like getting points off because i didnt use both order by clauses, But thanks!